# VMWare Fusion - automatically connect USB device to remote ESXi VM?

Tags: usb, vmware, vmware-fusion, esxi

I have an ESXi 6.0U3 server in my basement, and can access all of the VMs on it with VMWare Fusion Pro 11.5.7 on my laptop. This works very well, and can even connect USB devices connected to the laptop to the VM running on the server in the basement.

I'd like to know if it's possible to automatically connect local USB devices to the remote VM (when I'm connected to the backend server. I see that it's possible to do so if the VM is running locally on VMWare Fusion (https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1648), but I don't see a way to do this when connected to a remote VM.

In my particular case, it's for firmware development and the USB device will disconnect and reconnect a couple of times during the update process. I can manually reconnect (and dismiss the messages about the USB device disconnecting) but this becomes tedious and it'd be so much better if I could simply mark the USB VID:PID as autoconnect.

Is this possible?